# docker-compose rails with mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

Hello i have huge problem.
I'm trying to run rails and mysql on separate docker containers.
in docker-compose.yml i have :

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: zzz
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: zzz
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zzz
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

and in my rails database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: zzz
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: zzz
  host: database.dev //this is host for container with mysql
  port: 3306
```

end when i run application i got error :
`Access denied for user 'root'@'xxx' (using password: YES)` where xxx is ip my machine not container. Please help i dont know what to do

Comment: what is more when i try to access from my local machine ( rails s -p 9999 -> localhost:9999 ) everything is ok

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/links) the containers, this should work:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: zzz
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: zzz
      MYSQL_DATABASE: zzz
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
     - db:sql_srv
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Now the `web` container is linked to `db` and `sql_srv` is an alias for the `db` container. You should reach the `db` container from the `web` container using this address: `sql_srv:3306`

You don't actually need to specify the `ports` in the `db` container if you just want to connect your `db` container to the `web` container. The attribute `ports` is only used for reaching the container from the host.

Comment: Works perfectly. You saved my day. Thanks